# Expand v-treeview based on filtered results

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

In the tree view component, I would like to open all the nodes where there is some search text. But the expected is not happening.

Desired output: Open all the parents where there's some search text.
[image]
Here's the codepen for the same.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdxPKN?&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout wrap>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-text-field label="search" v-model="search" box />

        <v-treeview :items="tree"
          :search="search"
          active-class="grey lighten-4 indigo--text"
          item-key="name"
          open-on-click
          :open-all="{searchLength}>0?true:false"
          hoverable />
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats not happing?, working fine in the fiddle from what I can see.

Comment: Please check the image that I've added now. **Tree should be open while there's some search text.**

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview) , I don't think that possible *When `true` will cause all branch nodes to be opened when component is **mounted** .*

Comment: You need to work with the `open` prop, that should work

Comment: So you basically gonna have to provide the serach functionality by yourself, pass the filtered elements to the treeview, and the pass the keys of the filtered elements as an array to the `open` prop. That should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified totalhack's solution slightly to get what I wanted. Basically if there is a string in the search box I call updateAll(true).

```
<template>
<v-card>
  <v-card-title>File Open</v-card-title>
  <v-sheet class="pl-4 pr-4">
    <v-text-field
      label="Search"
      v-model="search"
      @input="handleSearch"
      flat
      solo-inverted
      hide-details
      clearable
      clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-sheet>
  <v-card-text>
    <v-container>
      <v-treeview
        ref="tree"
        :items="tree"
        :search="search"
        open-on-click
        return-object
        activatable
        dense
      >
        <template v-slot:prepend="{ item, open }">
          <v-icon v-if="!item.file">
            {{ open ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon v-else>
            {{ 'mdi-language-ruby' }}
          </v-icon>
        </template></v-treeview>
    </v-container>
  </v-card-text>
  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn color="primary" text @click="open()">Ok</v-btn>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn color="primary" text @click="show = false">Cancel</v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tree: [],
      search: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSearch(input) {
      if (input) {
        this.$refs.tree.updateAll(true)
      } else {
        this.$refs.tree.updateAll(false)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but unfortunately does not scale. I tried using this with a large tree object and it is painfully slow because the updateAll is called on all items I assume. Is there a workaround for large trees?

Answer (score 7):

So it got a little tricky, you can't use the builtin search functionality, but there's an acceptably easy workaround.

You basically have to implement the filter yourself, and just send the items you need to `v-treeview`.

Then you can create another computed property from your filteredElements which just return the `key` and pass it to the `:open` property of `treeview`.

Made a codepen for you.

https://codepen.io/brafols/pen/XwGQov

Comment: In your solution tree is expanded initially itself. If that's acceptable, below snippet will do.
<v-treeview :items="tree" :search="search"  active-class="grey lighten-4 indigo--text"              item-key="name" open-on-click :open-all="{searchLength}>0?true:false" hoverable>

But our desired output is to have them closed initially and open on search initiation.
    </v-treeview>

Comment: That should be fairly easy to modify, I gave you the idea, you can finish it yourself :D

Comment: I haven't checked whether `updateAll` is new relative to when this answer was posted but it appears you [can achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427162/10682164) with the built-in search now.

Comment: @Borjante Can you please help me implement a filter method for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591249/search-nested-array-of-js-objects-for-v-treeview/67591756?noredirect=1#comment119474328_67591756) please? I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach based off your example that works with the built-in search.

https://codepen.io/totalhack/pen/KKzzXvr

I added a search input event handler that uses the [treeview](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#api) `updateAll` function to open all items when a search starts. It then returns to the previous `open` state when the search text is empty. Note that if you use the built-in `clearable` prop of `v-text-field` you may need to handle events from that too (I haven't tried it).

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs6>        
          <v-text-field
            label="Search"
            v-model="search"
            @input="handleSearch"
            >         
          </v-text-field>
          <v-treeview 
            ref="tree"
            :items="tree"
            :search="search"
            :open.sync="open"
            open-on-click
            hoverable>
          </v-treeview>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return{
      search: '',
      open: [1],
      allOpened: false,
      lastOpen: [],
      tree: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Applications',
          children: [
            { id: 2, name: 'Calendar' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Chrome' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm' }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          name: 'Languages',
          children: [
            { id: 20, name: 'English' },
            { id: 30, name: 'French' },
            { id: 40, name: 'Spannish' }
          ]
        }
        
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSearch: function (val) {
      if (val) {
        if (!this.allOpened) {
          this.lastOpen = this.open;
          this.allOpened = true;
          this.$refs.tree.updateAll(true);
        }
      } else {
        this.$refs.tree.updateAll(false);
        this.allOpened = false;
        this.open = this.lastOpen;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you're asking yourself about how to search considering case sensitive, filter still works. I just made this:

```
filter () {
   return this.caseSensitive ? (item, search, textKey) =>  this.removeAccent(item[textKey].toLowerCase()).indexOf(this.removeAccent(search).toLowerCase()) > -1 : undefined
},
```

You just need to compare the search query the function without accents etc, with the same but to the item being compared by vuetify tree component internally.

In the component:

```
<v-treeview ref="tree" v-model="active" selectable :return-object="true" color="primary" selected-color="primary" :items="items" :search="searchOnTree" :filter="filter" @input="selected"></v-treeview>
```

To get the selected item (vuetify didn't say me it was this event) you just need to assign a function to an input event on the tree.