# Vuetify v-treeview doesn't open nested nodes

Tags: javascript, search, treeview, vuetify.js

I use v-textfild and v-treeview to search. When the result of searching is two-level, nodes open correctly. In the case of result is three-level, you can see only two-level opening of nodes. Why and how to open tree view to the deepest node? 
Example: the tree is

```
>A
  >B 
    >C
```

You are searching C. 
You can see as the result

```
>A
   >B (C is in B)
```

I use a standard node with fields 
id, 
name, 
children. 
Code for components:

```
<v-text-field label="search"
   v-model="searchHashtag"                                                              
   filled
</v-text-field>


<v-treeview
   :items="filteredElements"
   :open="filteredKeys"
   item-key="name"

   activatable
   color="warning"
   dense

   return-object
   hoverable>

      <template slot="label" slot-scope="{ item }">
         <a @click="onHashtagSelect(item)">{{ item.name }}</a>
      </template>

</v-treeview>
```

The result of search from logs: (v-treeview opens Country)

```
0:
  children: Array(1)
   0:
    children: Array(1)
      0: {id: 20, name: "France", children: Array(0)}
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array(0)
     id: 17
     name: "Country"
   __proto__: Object
   length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
  id: 16
  name: "world"
  __proto__: Object
  length: 
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this from totalhack:

```
<v-text-field
   label="Search"
   v-model="search"
   @input="handleSearch"
> 
</v-text-field>
    <v-treeview 
      ref="tree"
      :items="tree"
      :search="search"
      :open.sync="open"
      open-on-click
      hoverable>
    </v-treeview>


data(){
return{
  search: '',
  open: [1],
  allOpened: false,
  lastOpen: []
 } }

handleSearch: function (val) {
      if (val) {
        if (!this.allOpened) {
          this.lastOpen = this.open;
          this.allOpened = true;
          this.$refs.tree.updateAll(true);
        }
      } else {
        this.$refs.tree.updateAll(false);
        this.allOpened = false;
        this.open = this.lastOpen;
      }
    }
```

Reference
[Treeview open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427162/14246110)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: changed my answer and link to reference