# Search nested array of JS objects for v-treeview

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, search, vuetify.js

I am trying to implement a search functionality for my Vuetify `v-treeview` component using a filter function for an Array of nested JS objects that looks like.

```
[
   {
      Name: 'Name Level 1',
      Title: 'Title Level 1',
      children: [
         {
            Name: 'Name Level 2',
            Title: 'Title Level 2',
            children: [ ... ]
         }
      ]
   },
...
]
```

Right now I have text field that v-models to a search and a filter function that looks like the one from Bara Koc's comment.

```
filter () {
      return (item, search, textKey) => {
        let result = []
        const _filter = (item, search, textKey) => {
          for (const leaf of item) {
            if (leaf[textKey].indexOf(search) !== -1) {
              result = [...result, { Name: leaf.Name, Title: leaf.Title }]
            }
            if (leaf.children) {
              return _filter(leaf.children, search, textKey)
            } else {
              return null
            }
          }
        }
        _filter(item, search, textKey)
        return result
      }
    }
```

And the `v-treeview` looks like

```
<v-treeview
      :items="treeItems"
      :search="search"
      :filter="filter"
      :open.sync="open"
      item-key="Name"
      dense
      style="max-height: 700px;"
      class="overflow-y-auto overflow-x-auto"\>
```

where `search is` v-model`to a`v-text-field` as the string to search, but I get the following error.

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?5eb8:1888 TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the tree by a recursive function. You can think of the data structure as an M tree. Also I have used the closures for data encapsulation.

```js
const data = [
   {
      Name: 'Name Level 1',
      Title: 'Apple',
      children: [
         {
            Name: 'Name Level 2',
            Title: 'Title Level 2',
            children: [{
              Name: 'Name Level 3',
              Title: 'Application',
              children: null
            }]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      Name: 'Name Level 1',
      Title: 'Apple',
      children: null
   }
]

const filter = (item, search, textKey) => {
  let result = []
  const _filter = (item, search, textKey) => {
    for (const leaf of item) {
      if (leaf[textKey].indexOf(search) !== -1) {
        result = [...result, {Name: leaf.Name, Title: leaf.Title}]
      }
      leaf.children ? _filter(leaf.children, search, textKey) : null
    }
  }
  _filter(item, search, textKey)
  return result
}

console.log(filter(data, 'App', 'Title'))
```

Comment: Thank you @Bera Koc, just a quick question, I get `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` on the `            leaf.children ? _filter(leaf.children, search, 'Title') : null` line. Any idea why? I am guessing it is because I tried putting your filter const as a Vue.js method and pass it to the `v-treeview`.

Comment: I'm not that much into the Vue. There has to be some data difference in Vue. Since the function is pure, I think sending it would not cause any error. From looking the error message, I think the way you send it is wrong. I wish I could help you more.